# How to write method for Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, arraylist, linked-list, android-sqlite

I am creating a sample gallery app, I am trying to store Gallery Items in local sqlite database

Sample query:

```
select filed1 from tablename where filed2="66547";

        public List<String> getAllLabels(String number){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        String foldername;

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = " SELECT " + Databaseconnect.FILEPATH + " FROM "+     Databaseconnect.TABLE_FILE + " WHERE" + Databaseconnect.FOLDERLINK="+"number;



        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```

Still I have error , how to write List in this query.. please given me solutions

Comment: please some one solution for my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one :

```
String selectQuery =" SELECT " + Databaseconnect.FILEPATH + " FROM "+Databaseconnect.TABLE_FILE + " WHERE " + Databaseconnect.FOLDERLINK + "=" + String.valueOf(number) + ";";
```